# Unable to set isRichText to true with Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, chatter, html, feeditem

I have a flow that copy a Chatter post to the chatter of a related record. The issue is that there are unwanted html tags added to the chatter of the related records:

[image]

I try to update the record of all the feeditem last modified by this flow, but isRichText is still set to "false" after the flow interview ends. Here's my "Update Records" element.
[image]

Is it possible to set it to true with a flow or do I need to code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Post to Chatter action provided with Flow doesn't support rich text. However, there's a [Post Rich Chatter](https://unofficialsf.com/post-rich-chatter-invocable-action/) extension that you can install that does.